# How to get data inside the inline fragment in graphql?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I have a query with inline fragment like this:

```
const GET_PRODUCTS = gql`
    query MyQuery {
        products(where: {featured: false}) {
            edges {
            node {
                //.. other field that not related 
                productId
                name
                onSale
                ... on VariableProduct {
                    id
                    name
                    price
                    regularPrice(format: FORMATTED)
                    salePrice(format: FORMATTED)
                    variations {
                        nodes {
                        id
                        name
                        variationId
                        price(format: FORMATTED)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }`
}
```

Then in GraphiQL ide it product the result like this:

```
{
    "data": {
      "products": {
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              // .. all other field that not related
              "productId": 26,
              "name": "",
              "onSale": true,
              "variations": {
                "nodes": [
                  {
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "DEF example",
                    "variationId": 31,
                    "price": "$0.00"
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 2"",
                    "name": "DEF example",
                    "variationId": 31,
                    "price": "$0.00"
                  },
                  
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              .... another same node
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              .. another node
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Calling the query using Apollo Client:

```
import GET_PRODUCTS from '../queries/get-product'

const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_PRODUCTS);
```

Then I want to get the value of field `id`,`name`, `variationId` and `price` inside `variations`'s `node` array.

Therefore I do like this in my React:

```
{data && data.products.edges.map(({ node }) => (
        <ProductCell
              product={node}
         />              
 ))}
```

With the code above, I able to get the value of `productId`, `name`, `onSale` field in my `ProductCell` component by doing this:

```
const ProductCell = (props) => {
   return(
    <div>
      <p>{props.product.productId}</p>
      <p>{props.product.name}</p>
      <p>{props.product.onSale}</p>
    </div>
   ) 
}
```

Now the problem is I want to get the value inside `variation`'s `node array, I doing like this in` ProductCell`, which I hope it will return me "DEF example" for 2 times:

```
{props.product.variations.nodes.map(({ node }) => (
     <p>node.name<p>
))}
```

But end up, I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodes' of undefined

Therefore this basically means that can't get the `nodes` inside `variations` in the `product` object. Ok I get that, therefore I checked for console log in the browser, I get this:

```
product:
    onSale: true
    productId: 10
    name: abc
    __typename: "VariableProduct"
    __proto__:
    constructor: ƒ Object()
    hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
    isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
    propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
    toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
    toString: ƒ toString()
    valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
    __defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
    __defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
    __lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
    __lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
    get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
    set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
    __proto__: Object
```

The field of `name`, `product` and `onSale` is existed, so I can get it in `ProductCell`, but
the `variations` field which is under `... on VariableProduct` section of the query is not existed.

**Question:**

So my question is,

1. How to get the value of `id`, `name`, `variationId` field inside `variation` `node`?
2. Why browser not get the json response like I get in GraphiQL above? Instead it return an Object for the part of `... on VariableProduct` in the query?

**Edit:**

This is from Network tab of dev tools in my browser:

[image]

As you can see, there are no `variations` key in the response, instead it become `__typename: VariableProduct` then I cant expand it anymore

Comment: graphql client? apollo? response body has this info?

Comment: ya I using apollo client

Comment: and I updated the question as well

Comment: network response body checked?

Comment: I didnt check network response yet.. Cause I dont know how to check.. But the graphql is in localhost, not sure is it a problem.

Comment: just search in browser dev tools/network - POST /grapgql request, select it, check response

Comment: Ah I see.. I check the browser Network tab, I can get the response.. The response is almost same like my query, just the Variable product it become an object. I updated the question for the result

Comment: compare requests body with graphiql request

Comment: In GraphiQL I can get the `variations{node{ ... and all the stuff} }` as a  Json.. But in browser, I can't do that, it become `__typename:VariableProduct`

Comment: compare requests, not responses, this time

Comment: I'm very sorry, but how can I compare the request again? haha.. Where can I check that?

Comment: the same place - network

Comment: Bro thank you very much, I now noticed that I calling the wrong query..My request query is wrong